# Prove or disprove: All radial vector fields are conservative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, vectors, fake-proofs

This was a question a calculus student had asked me, and unfortunately I believe I gave an incorrect proof.

> **DEFINITION**: A radial vector field is defined by ${\bf F}(x,y) = g(x,y){\bf r},$ where $g$ is a scalar function and ${\bf r}= \langle x,y\rangle$ is a vector.

At the time, I did not know the complete definition of a radial vector field. I proved it like so:

**PROOF**: Let $a,b\in\mathbb R$. Take ${\bf F}(x,y) = ax{\mathrm i} + by\mathrm j$. Consider the function $f(x,y) = {1\over2}ax^2 + {1\over2}by^2$. Then clearly $\nabla f(x,y) = ax\mathrm i + by\mathrm j = {\bf F}(x,y)$, hence all radial vector fields are conservative.

However, this is not correct because it only works for *fixed* constants $a,b$. For a general function $g(x,y)$, what might we be able to do? The more I think about it, the less I think the conjecture is true but I can't think of a counter example.

Comment: This is not generally true. A conservative vector field will have a curl of $0$, which means the vector field is not rotating. Consider placing a radial vector field over the unit circle. A curl of $0$ implies that if you sum up the components of the field parallel to the surface of the circle, you get $0$. In mathematical terms, you could say that for $P$ being the i-component of **$F$** and $Q$ the j-component,

$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$

Comment: The claim would be correct if you define a radial vector field as $\mathbf{F} = g(r) \mathbf{r}$ with $r = \lvert \mathbf{r} \rvert$. Please see my post below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the radial vector field

$$
F(x, y) = (x^2, xy) = x (x, y).
$$

Note that the $x$-component of this field is everywhere nonnegative, and mostly positive. Integrate it over the sides of the square with vertices $(0,0), (1, 0), (1,1), (0, 1)$ and the $x$-coordinate of the result will be nonzero. But for a conservative field, the integral over any cycle is always zero.

Hence not every radial field is conservative.

Alternatively: A field $F$ on a simply connected domain is conservative only if $\partial F_y/\partial x =\partial F_x / \partial y$ everywhere. In the case of this field, that would require that 
$$y = 0$$
which is not everywhere true.

Answer (score 1):

As written, you're right, because the $x$ component is (taking the non-unit $\mathbf{r}$ for convenience) $g(x,y) x$ and the $y$ component is $g(x,y) y$. There is no reason to expect $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(g(x,y) x)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} x$ to be the same as $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} y$.

A case that would work would be $f(x) e_1 + g(y) e_2$. In this case you can just find antiderivatives of $f$ and $g$ and add them together.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is already answered above. However there is a subclass of radial vector fields defined as  $\mathbf{v} = f(r) \mathbf{r}$ where $r = \lvert \mathbf{r} \rvert$, $\mathbf{r} = x \mathbf{i} + y \mathbf{j} + z \mathbf{k}$ which are always conservative. Such vector fields occur naturally when considering gravitational fields for example. Thus sometimes they are taken as definition of a radial vector field.

Proof. $\mathbf{v} = f(r) \mathbf{r}$ is conservative if we can find $F$ such that
$$
\nabla F(r) = F'(r) \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r} = \mathbf{v}
$$
which implies that $F'(r) = r f(r)$. Since any continuous function has an anti derivative, we can always find $F$ as long as $f$ is continuous.

Example. Take $f(r) = \cos r$. Then $F(r) = \sin r - r \cos r$.

Comment: But your "usual definition" is **not** the one OP is working with. I would have said that your definition matches the notion of "radially symmetric vector field" perhaps. As for the "usual definition," I'd say that one person's "usual" is another person's "different." [We also all tend to think that the first definition we encounter is the 'usual' one, alas.] (Example: pick almost any word used in both mathematics and physics... :) )

Comment: Hi John. Yes you are right. I thought this was the usual definition but searching on the web left me thinking that there is no "usual definition". But I think this is still an important subcase of the question of the OP that deserves a little bit of explanation.

Comment: I agree that it's an interesting subcase. Perhaps the one thing I'd have done differently would be to rewrite the first sentence, saying something like what Ian wrote ("This **isn't** an answer to the question asked. As asked, others have shown...") and then continue with "but there's *another* definition of 'radial field' that might have brought some readers here, and for which the claim is true." I try to  start answers like this with "**Not an answer, but a related note**", or others of a different kind with "**Not an answer, but a general hint**". Others make different choices, of course.